# Applying OUTER JOIN on VIEWS

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have created a view from the following question:

"Create a view to select employee ID, employee name, hire date, and department number."

Here is my query:

```
CREATE VIEW SIMPVIEW AS
SELECT EMPNO, ENAME, HIREDATE,DEPTNO
FROM EMP;
```

As clear from the above query, the view name is **"SIMPVIEW"**. Now I'm trying to write another query in response to the following question:

"Use the view you just created in a select statement joined with the department table to list employee id,employee name, department name, and hire date."

I understand that basically I need to **JOIN** the view I created earlier and the fields of department table somehow and hence I have two questions:

Since I have to include all the elements from **SIMPVIEW** view, is there any way I can select all the elements from the view without selecting each and every element which I have done below.

`SELECT s.empno,s.ename,s.hirdate,s.deptno,d.dname FROM   SIMPVIEW s LEFT OUTER JOIN Dept d ON s.empno = d.deptno;`

**My QUESTION:** Is the above query correct?

Here are the two tables(DEPT and EMP) for your reference:

```
DEPT

DEPTNO,DNAME,LOC

EMP

EMPNO, ENAME,JOB,MGR,HIREDATE,SAL,COMM,DEPTNO
```

Comment: I see no need for an outer join.

Comment: @DanBracuk: You might be right. However, it might be so that some employees were not assigned to any particular department.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join based on `deptno`, so your query should look like

```
SELECT s.empno,
       s.ename,
       s.hirdate,
       s.deptno,
       d.dname 
FROM SIMPVIEW s 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN Dept d ON s.deptno = d.deptno;
```

And yes, you can rewrite the query as

```
SELECT s.*,
       d.dname 
FROM SIMPVIEW s 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN Dept d ON s.deptno = d.deptno;
```

Comment: Thank you for your valuable input.

Answer (score 0):

It never hurts to read the question.  You are asked for a query that produces 4 columns; yours produces 5.  Therefore the answer to "is it correct?" is No.

Next, you don't say how the tables are related.  It *might* be that `EMP.EMPNO` is a foreign key to `DEPT.DEPTNO` but that would be, to say the least, unconventional!  Absent other information, I would assume

1. that the question intends you to join based on `EMP.DEPTNO =`DEPT.DEPTNO`, and
2. that an employee must be in a department and `EMP.DEPTNO` cannot be NULL.

in which case a simple inner `JOIN` will do.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable input.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this is what you required

```
Create or replace view simpview 
(empno, ename, hirdate, deptno,dname  )
AS
SELECT s.empno,
       s.ename,
       s.hirdate,
       s.deptno,
       d.dname 
FROM SIMPVIEW s 
   LEFT OUTER JOIN Dept d 
ON s.deptno = d.deptno;
```

Comment: Thank you for your valuable input.